# How to display an array as an option tag

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So basically i'm still new to this and I have made function in javascript that changes a button into a an option tag thing so I can choose between 0-4. Now I want to change the options so i can pick from an array and I don't know how to do it. I tried changing the 5 in the code into the name of the array but I got no options.

```
    function start()
{
  let i = 0; ih= "<select id = 'fighter'>"
  for(; i < 5; i++)
  ih+= "<option value= " + i + ">" + i + "</option>";
  ih+= "</select>";
    document.getElementById("arena").innerHTML = ih;
}


var fighters =  [
{
  "name":"Abdi",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 20,
},
{
  "name": "chriz",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 40,
}

]
```

Comment: you are not clear, what do you mean by array?

Comment: basically I have an array with bunch of names in it and I'm trying to change the HTML so I can pick from there instead. ` 

var fighters =  [
{
  "name":"Abdi",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 20,
},
{
  "name": "chriz",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 40,
}

]

`

Comment: no right now i have 1 ,2 , 4, 5 I want to change that so I can pick from an array that has a bunch of names in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```js
var fighters = [{
  "name": "Abdi",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 20
}, {
  "name": "chriz",
  "HP": 100,
  "DMG": 40
}];

for (var fighter of fighters) list.innerHTML += `<option value="${fighter.name}">${fighter.name}</option>`;
```

```html
<select id="list"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fighters = [ { "name":"Abdi", "HP": 100, "DMG": 20, }, { "name": "chriz", "HP": 100, "DMG": 40, } ]; 

let mySelect = document.createElement("SELECT");
    
        for(figther of fighters)
        {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.text = fighter.name;
             option.value = fighter.DMG;
             mySelect.appendChild(option);
        
        }
        
        document.getElementById("arena").appendChild(mySelect);
```

Comment: its better to use document.createElement, instead of appending the html directly, because if you append the html directly, the page, has to reparse all the html file and rerender all the page.

Comment: idk why but that's not doing anything.

Comment: yeah the problem was that you spelled fighter.name instead of fighters.name but still it created an option thing that says "undefined"